# Java VisualVM heap space dump into output path

Tags: java, dump, visualvm

I need to know if it is possible to declare a output path for a heap space dump in the java visualVM. Is there any parameter that I can use for the java visual VM?

I have to trace a specific service on my server and need to get a dump of the heap space.

thanks.

***UPDATE***

Thanks a lot. I found a solution for my problem. I connected to my service with jmx remote. There it is possible to save the heapdump on any other drive of the server.

Comment: Can you please explain, why do you need to change output path for heap dump. If you need a heap dump of your monitored application, you can take a heap dump from VisualVM. There is no need to change the output path.

Comment: There is no free space on my main partition to save the heap dump.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following `visualvm.tmpdir` system property to change the directory, where VisualVM stores snapshots, thread dumps and heap dumps. Usage:

```
visualvm -J-Dvisualvm.tmpdir=[custom_tmp_dir]
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Dead link removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can change location of the temporary directory that VisualVM uses inside of /etc/visualvm.conf file as follows:

```
    visualvm_default_options=" ...  -J-Djava.io.tmpdir=<PATH> -J-Dvisualvm.tmpdir=<THE SAME PATH>"
```

Answer (score 2):

For VisualVM 1.4.4 the following settings are needed in `etc/visualvm.conf`:

```
visualvm_default_userdir="<set-your-path>"
visualvm_default_options="<...> -J-Djava.io.tmpdir=<set-your-path>"
```

- `visualvm_default_userdir` sets it for **jmx** based heap dumps.
- `visualvm_default_options` sets it for **process** based heap dumps.